# janus or pjsip for rtp-rtcp implementation

Tags: webrtc, rtp, pjsip, rtcp, janus-gateway

I am evaluating implementation of a simple SFU for webRTC. I have looked cursorily at the two source codes but find that support for REMB and PLI is missing in pjsip.  How come it works with WebRTC then?

I just want a simple gateway so I can forward RTP packets with RTCP feedback in both directions. I am looking for a C language implementation.

I see no comparison between Janus and pjsip.  Anyone having worked on the two can point the pros and cons of the two or possibly a third option?

Comment: Audio would work without REMB and PLI. Video would work without REMB but you'd likely need PLIs to handle keyframe requests.

Comment: @Josh Mackey With WebRTC media, there would be need for support of both REMB and PLI. So, which one supports the maximum RTCP types? pjsip or janus?

Comment: Unknown, I only noted that WebRTC would still work without those RTCP types.

Comment: @asinix: Any approach you could figure out? I want to implement a RTP SFU where all participants are connected and assigned unique SSRC, based on request from each participant via other signalling plane, packets received from set/allowed SSRC's are forwarded to all participants

Comment: @Chakri I wrote a SFU on my own... Linux-based... wrote everything from scratch. Learned a lot along the way... the best way to go.  Takes time and a lot of patience. Almost there...

Comment: @asinix: Can you please share me some pointers on how to start learning to write RTP SFU for use case similar as I mentioned above, Is there any good library to use for immediate use?

Comment: @Chakri Take a look at open source SFUs like jitsi or janus, for example. Or peon if you are into Go.